# How should I include metadata in a solidjs app?

Tags: javascript, html, metadata, solid-js

I am building a webapp with solidjs, I would like to include page title, description, meta image etc. I would like to be able to access these dynamically with javascript.

I have tried adding the equivalent html elements within the jsx, but this did not work.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the proper solution is to use [solid meta](https://github.com/solidjs/solid-meta) found on github. Usage looks like this for a client side  only app:

`pnpm i @solidjs/meta`

```
import { MetaProvider, Title, Link, Meta } from '@solidjs/meta';

const App = () => (
  <MetaProvider>
    <div class="Home">
      <Title>Title of page</Title>
      <Link rel="canonical" href="http://solidjs.com/" />
      <Meta name="example" content="whatever" />
      // ...
    </div>
  </MetaProvider>
);
```

Comment: This seems to work for the visitor of the page, but the meta data comes up as null when posted to social media or a metadata checker.